# forward or backward IntegerDigits in pairs must yield different results

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation, digits

I have some pair configurations same as `{0,1,1,1,0,1}` with `{1,0,1,1,0,1}` or `{1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1}` with `{1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1}`. I wish to define a function whose duty is distinguish the first pair from the second ones.

For the first pair all digits are same except two first digits `01` and `10`

```
{0,1,1,1,0,1}
{1,0,1,1,0,1}
```

For the last pair, all digits are same except the middle digits `10` and `01`.

```
{1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1}
{1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1}
```

I wish to define a function that when it faces to the first pairs, in which `01` in ( for example `{0,1,1,1,0,1}` ) is ahead of `10` in ( for example `{1,0,1,1,0,1}`) yields `-1` and for the second configuration yields `+1`.

The number of digits and the positions of them are not important. For a pair, being forward or backward of `01` is important.

I wrote the below line, for example for the last pairs

```
Do[
If[Quotient[
    FromDigits[{1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 2] - 
     FromDigits[{1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 2], 2^(k - 1)] == 1, 
  Print@k], {k, 1, 8}]
```

and for the first pair

```
Do[If[Quotient[
     FromDigits[{0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, 2] - 
      FromDigits[{1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, 2], 2^(k - 1)] == -1 && 
   Mod[FromDigits[{0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, 2] - 
      FromDigits[{1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, 2], 2^(k - 1)] == 0 , 
  Print@k], {k, 1, 6}]
```

In general we can say:

```
If[Quotient[
         FromDigits[list1, 2] - 
          FromDigits[list2, 2], 2] < 0 && 
       Mod[FromDigits[list1, 2] - 
          FromDigits[list2, 2], 2] == 0, Print[list1,list2]]
```

in which list1 and list2 are ordered above pairs, can make a reasonable difference between pairs.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not sure what you mean, in particular, by "For a pair, being forward or backward of 01 is important." It seems that `If[#1 > #2, 1, -1] &[firstnumber, secondnumber]` gives the output you want for those examples, but I'm guessing that's not what you're after in general.

Comment: I am probably misreading this one, but maybe `Pick[lista,listb, 
  0] // Signature`, or some better use of `Signature`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the operation is on zeros and ones then you may use [Bitwise Operations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/BitwiseOperations.html) like [`BitXor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BitXor.html).

```
f[x_, y_] := Subtract @@ Pick[x, BitXor[x, y], 1]
```

Then

```
f[{0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}]
```

> ```
> -1
> ```

and

```
f[{1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Does the following work for you?

```
order[l : {a___, b_, c_, d___}, {a___, c_, b_, d___}] /; MatchQ[l, {(0 | 1) ..}] := b - c
order[_, _] := "Invalid" (*optional, provides fallback if the two arguments are invalid*)

order[{0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}]
(* -1 *)

order[{1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}]
(* 1 *)
```

The first definition only matches if you have two lists with two of their elements flipped. The [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) (`/;`) makes sure that the lists only consist of `0` and `1` (you can drop it if you don't need to be so strict)